# Convergence of two arbitrary points in compact connected, metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a compact connected, metric space.
Can we say, for any two-point $x,\,y\in X$ there is a sequence $\{a_i\}$ from $x$ to $y$ such that $a_0=x,\, a_i\in B_{d(x,\,y)}(y),\, \lim_{i\to \infty}a_i=y$ ?

Note, $B_{d(x,\,y)}(y)$ is a ball with  $d(x,\,y)$ radius and $y$ center.

Answer (score 2):

Without any further assumptions, the sequence $a_0=x$, $a_i=y$ for $i>0$, satisfies your requirements.

Comment: I think the OP should clarify the notation.  I would have expected $B_{d(x, y)}(y)$ to be the open ball, so $x \not\in B_{d(x, y)}(y)$.

Comment: Chris Eagle: the example I've given works whether you take open or closed balls centred on $y$.

Comment: Almost... the question wanted $a_0 = x$ and $a_0 \in B_{d(x, y)}(y)$, which is impossible with the open ball.  I suppose the closed ball must have been intended, so my previous comment is irrelevant.

Comment: Another (silly?) point: if $x=y$ then the ball is empty so the sequence does no exist!

Comment: The case of $a_0$ not being in the open ball is a bit silly, clearly the ball requirement would have to be for $i>0$.

As for the $y=x$ case, fair point!

The question I suspect might have been intended is the one where the balls are taken open and centred around $x$.